# using fragment following the template primary/details on android studio

Tags: java, android

I tried using the template primary/details in Android studio.
in the first rows I found in ItemDetailsHostActivity the element "ActivityItemDetailBinding" in onCreate method, but I have not found docs about that class, neither in android.developers nor in google.
someone can explain me the use and where  found docs?.
thanks

P.B.

I try using fragment and I would like some suggestions to understand in code found in template

I found the code in the supplied template Primary/detail in android studio  Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1.
the code is the following:

```
public class ItemDetailHostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActivityItemDetailBinding binding = ActivityItemDetailBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_item_detail);
        NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.
                Builder(navController.getGraph())
                .build();

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    }
```

the xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_item_detail"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/primary_details_nav_graph"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_item_detail" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I do not understand what is:

ActivityItemDetailBinding binding = ActivityItemDetailBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

it seems a class, but where are the docs?.
if it is a resource..I don't understand where to find the related information.

I am new to android programming, although i know java and c ++ quite well. i'm new in stackoverflow too and i apologize if i'm breaking any post management rules..
thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am using android studio Dolphin  2021.3.1 Patch 1, using the supplied primary/details template. I found the folllowing code in the main activity:

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the project is using `DataBinding`. Classes `*DataBinding` are not classes(in core meaning) but they are layout resources for which the binding is generated.

For your case, it is `activity_item_detail.xml`

Comment: thanks @TheLil,
I found the code in the supplied template Primary/detail in android studio  Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1.
the code is the following:
'''